# Count the number of faces in a vertex group and its total area

Tags: python, add-on, vertices, vertex-groups

I need to count in my scene for each possible vertex group (in each mesh) the number of faces of that vertex group and its total area (the sum of the areas of its faces).
I made this first solution even with your help but it is still not enough, in my addon 5-6 seconds are wasted to perform this function and I would like something faster, consider that the test was done on a mesh with 230,000 vertices and 500,000 faces, how can I make it more efficient?

```
def count_face_area(obj, num_groups):
    group_faces = [0] * num_groups #list with the total number of faces for each vertex group
    area = [0] * num_groups #list with the total area for each vertex group
    
    vertices = obj.data.vertices
    polygons = obj.data.polygons

    for face in polygons:
        group_counts = [0] * num_groups
        for vertex_idx in face.vertices:
            vertex = vertices[vertex_idx]
            for vgroup in vertex.groups:
                group_counts[vgroup.group] += 1
                
        for group_idx, count in enumerate(group_counts):
            if count == len(face.vertices):
                group_faces[group_idx] += 1
                area[group_idx] += face.area
                break

    return group_faces, area
```

Imagine that this function is inside a `for` loop that iterates through all the meshes of my scene so the obj parameter will be a mesh at each loop `(obj = bpy.data.objects["mymesh"]), num_groups` instead is the number of total vertex group

Comment: your code in this question is not properly indented. i think that last `for` loop needs to be inside the main `for` loop. but how deep inside should it be. should it be a fourth level loop?

Answer (score 0):

One problem I found in your code is that you are repetitively accessing the same properties (dot notation) over and over again that is additional overhead per iteration which can reduce performance. Run the script and notice that the modified function i made called `count_face_area_40_percent_faster` stores several properties in new variables which leads to better performance than the original `count_face_area` function. Compare the time elapsed which you can see in the *system console*.

I was able to decrease the processing time by 40% just by declaring the following line outside of the `for` loop:

```
vertices = obj.data.vertices
```

Here to demonstrate the performance difference with a simple `for` loop.

```
import bpy
import time

iter = 500000
x = None

def test_slow(obj):
    for i in range(iter):
        x = bpy.context.object.data.vertices[0]

def test_fast(obj):
    vertices = obj.data.vertices

    for i in range(iter):
        x = vertices[0]

print("start ====>")

start = time.time()
test_slow(bpy.context.object)
end = time.time()
print("elapsed time =======> test_slow:", end - start)

start = time.time()
test_fast(bpy.context.object)
end = time.time()
print("elapsed time =======> test_fast:", end - start)
```

[image]

```
import bpy
import time

def count_face_area(obj, num_groups):
    group_faces = [0] * num_groups #list with the total number of faces for each vertex group
    area = [0] * num_groups #list with the total area for each vertex group

    for face in obj.data.polygons:
        group_counts = [0] * num_groups
        for vertex_idx in face.vertices:
            vertex = obj.data.vertices[vertex_idx]
            for vgroup in vertex.groups:
                group_counts[vgroup.group] += 1
                for group_idx, count in enumerate(group_counts):
                    if count == len(face.vertices):
                        group_faces[group_idx] += 1
                        area[group_idx] += face.area
                        break

    return group_faces, area


def count_face_area_40_percent_faster(obj, num_groups):
    group_faces = [0] * num_groups #list with the total number of faces for each vertex group
    area = [0] * num_groups #list with the total area for each vertex group

    vertices = obj.data.vertices

    for face in obj.data.polygons:
        group_counts = [0] * num_groups
        for vertex_idx in face.vertices:
            vertex = vertices[vertex_idx]
            for vgroup in vertex.groups:
                group_counts[vgroup.group] += 1
                
                for group_idx, count in enumerate(group_counts):
                    if count == len(face.vertices):
                        group_faces[group_idx] += 1
                        area[group_idx] += face.area
                        break

    return group_faces, area

print("start ====>")

start = time.time()
count_face_area(bpy.context.object, 0)
end = time.time()
print("elapsed time =======>   original:", end - start)

start = time.time()
count_face_area_40_percent_faster(bpy.context.object, 0)
end = time.time()
print("elapsed time =======> 40% faster:", end - start)
```

[image]

So i hope you get the idea.

Comment: it seems that in your code there is an indentation problem, in fact your solution is more efficient but the data that is returned to me is completely wrong, if I put everything inside the "for" loop that iterates all the faces then the data is correct but I lose efficiency again and the situation does not change with respect to my solution

Comment: ah i know why, because your code has the indentation problem. I can see your `for group_idx, count in enumerate(group_counts):` loop is not indented to be included in the main for loop. try copy your code in your question and paste it into blender. that is the one that is incorrect.

Comment: i updated my answer, assuming that you wanted the `for` loop to be on the 4th sub iteration level.

Comment: I'm sorry in fact I had not seen that I made a mistake in reporting the code, I corrected it, despite this your solution still does not give me efficient results

Comment: then ur doing something wrong. have u tried the sample code? it clearly is way faster. i can see `obj.data.vertices` is still in your loop. it needs to be outside declared outside the loop

Comment: I wanted to ask you something, why do you always pass the value "0" as the second parameter of the function? That should be the number of vertex groups of the considered mesh

Comment: its only a sample. you can pass the value you need. did u understand the idea i conveyed in my answer about dot notation and its overhead?

Comment: yes I made the changes you recommended but I get very minimal improvements, I changed the code again you can look it

Comment: how many seconds did it take before the change and how many seconds after the change?

Comment: before the change about 4, after the change about 3.6

Comment: can u share ur blend file? https://blend-exchange.com .. im really curious why it doesnt work for ur setup.

Comment: the file is too big, 66 mb, the maximum is 30

Comment: try reducing the size or try dropbox